# upgraded to wp 4.0 - getting convert_to_screen() errors with WP_List_Table

Tags: wp-list-table

I upgraded my wordpress to 4.0 any my plugin which has a class that extends from WP_List_Table is now throwing this error

```
[30-Sep-2014 21:40:55 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function
convert_to_screen() in /home/xxxx/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-list-table.php on line 101
```

I reinstalled wp 4.0 and the source code for the table class can be seen here
       https://github.com/emeraldjava/bhaawp/blob/master/includes/listtable/raceresulttable.class.php

Any ideas?